# How to add multiple styles on an echart label

Tags: css, angular, typescript, echarts

wanted to see if anyone knew how can I have for example a bold text and a regular text on a label for the x or y axis on an echart, here is the code for the simple chart axis and an example

```
xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          data: xAxisData,
          name: 'DATE (MM/DD)',
```

Comment: I realized I couldn't add a picture, but it is to have for example DATE in with 700 weight and the (MM/YY) on 400 weight